# Teams Document Tab Content URL Access Issue for External Users

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

We are currently developing a Power Automate to integrate file tabs into Teams channels. According to the latest information from Microsoft, the website tab in Teams is slated for deprecation. Consequently, we explored using the Document tab as a viable alternative.

However, when attempting to add the Document tab, we encountered an issue. A content URL is required, and unfortunately, guest users in the Teams environment are unable to access the document when we add the Document tab using a content URL. Our objective is to ensure that the Document tab is accessible to all members, regardless of whether they are guests or regular members. We aim for universal permission access.

Has anyone else ever faced this issue?

Comment: To address this issue and ensure universal permission access, you can consider using SharePoint as an alternative solution. By adding a Microsoft Teams tab in SharePoint as an SPFx web part, you can achieve a rich integration experience between Teams and SharePoint.
You can integrate your document tab within SharePoint, which provides more flexibility in terms of permissions and access control.
For more information and detailed steps, you can refer to the [Add Teams tab to SharePoint - Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tabs-in-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

To address this issue and ensure universal permission access, you can consider using SharePoint as an alternative solution. By adding a Microsoft Teams tab in SharePoint as an SPFx web part, you can achieve a rich integration experience between Teams and SharePoint. You can integrate your document tab within SharePoint, which provides more flexibility in terms of permissions and access control. For more information and detailed steps, you can refer to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tabs-in-sharepoint